# Store UTC date string in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, timezone

How can I store this date string `new Date().toUTCString()` in MySQL without converting to any other formats? I've already tried saving this value in a `DATETIME` column, and `0000-00-00 00:00:00` was inserted instead of something like `Tue, 14 Apr 2015 14:11:40 GMT`.

Comment: Use a `VARCHAR` datatype.

Comment: @Barmar Is that the best solution?

Comment: If you want to store the string, not the time value, why would there be any better solution?

Comment: @Barmar It's still a datetime value. And it's just another format containing timezone. Why wouldn't the MySQL `Datetime` datatype support it?

Comment: I see what you're asking for. Check out the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
STR_TO_DATE(:utcstring, '%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s GMT')
```

Comment: `GMT` part doesn't work, causes result to be `NULL`.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer I just tried `select str_to_date('Tue, 14 Apr 2015 14:11:40 GMT', '%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s GMT');` and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You better use `DATETIME` datatype in MySQL.

And use this function, to insert an UTC value: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

```
new Date().toISOString()
"2015-04-14T14:53:07.940Z"
```

PHP:

```
(new DateTime())->format('c')
```

MySQL:

```
`createdAt` = now()
```

Comment: He says he doesn't want to use another format like `toISOString`, he wants to use `toUTCString`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that MySQL will automatically remove  timezone if I store date in ISO format.

Comment: Do you need to store timezone?

Comment: Then Barmar’s answer is not approriate, because it uses only GMT/UTC, like mine.